# DOM removing selected child nodes

Tags: php, dom, removechild

I have a dom element with html inside chat contains some html elements I'd like to remove, while still keeping some tags that are ok.

I try to iterate through child elements all child elements and delete those that need to be removed

```
foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element)
    if ($element->nodeName != 'br')
        $node->removeChild($element);
```

But this throws a Not Found Error exception which not being caught causes a fatal error.
How would I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following instead to remove the node:

```
$element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
```

Comment: not working for me  , now showing any errors as well.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName('*')` finds all *descendent* elements, not *child* elements.  So some of the `$element` you want to remove are not children of `$node`, hence the failure.

I'm not 100% sure what your intention is here, but most likely you just want to remove certain *immediate* children. In this case, do the following:

```
$nodestoremove = array();
foreach ($node->childNodes as $n) {
    if ($n->nodeType===XML_ELEMENT_NODE and $n->nodeName!=='br') {
        $nodestoremove[] = $n;
    }
}
foreach ($nodestoremove as $n) {
    $node->removeChild($n);
}
unset($nodestoremove); // so nodes can be garbage-collected

echo $node->C14N(); // xml fragment after removal
```

Note that we make two passes: one to identify the nodes to delete, and a second pass to delete. This is because `childNodes` is an active list, so we can't iterate through it forwards as we delete. (Although we could iterate through it backwards.)